# Probability Arithmetic/Algebra Rules

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, inequality, arithmetic

Occasionally, I see arithmetic/algebraic operations performed in the context of equations or inequalities that include the $\Pr()$ function.  $\Pr()$ is an unusual animal, because it can live within an equation or inequality, and its input is another equation or inequality.  For example, $$\Pr(X < 2) = \frac{3}{5},$$$$\Pr(X > 4) = \Pr(X < 2) + \frac{1}{2},$$$$1 < \Pr(\Pr(X = 5) \le X).$$  When these start being manipulated, i.e., to normalize random variables, I'm a bit unclear on what rules apply.  For example, in the second equation, to multiply both sides of $X < 2$ by $10$, do we also need to multiple both sides of $X > 4$ by $10$?  Do we also multiply $\frac{1}{2}$ by $10$?  If we multiply both sides of the third equation by $2$, do we distribute the $2$ to the innermost equation, $X = 5$?  What about squaring both sides, etc.?

What would be a simple list of rules that explains how to manipulate these equations in the way ordinary algebraic equations are manipulated at a high school level?

Comment: The argument passed into the $Pr(~)$ operator is generally an *event*, a subset of your sample space.  That event may involve a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) and may be shorthanded as you see above.  You may change how the event is represented so long as the actual event it describes is not different.  As a set, the set of all values $x$ who satisfy $x<2$ is the same as the set of all values $x$ who satisfy $10x<20$, so you could if you want rewrite $Pr(X<2)$ as $Pr(10X<20)$, and in doing so nothing else in the equation needs to change.

Comment: Any manipulations you make to the outside of a term which is a probability however, *remain* outside.  For example, with $10\cdot Pr(X<2)$ there is nothing that can be done to somehow "move the 10 inside."

Comment: @JMoravitz: That looks like a full answer to me.